# Python 3 try except issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, except

I'm having a little issue with my code, mainly (I think) with the try/except part. My code will generate a wordlist of the users choice. Here is the code:

```
def gen_wordlist():
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the wordlist:  ")

    try:
        my_file = open(filename, 'r')

    except FileNotFoundError:
        retry = input("No file named "+filename+". Would you like to try again (y/n)")
        if retry == 'y' or retry == 'Y':
            gen_wordlist()
        else:
            print("Goodbye :-)")
            sys.exit()

    words = my_file.read()
    my_file.close()
    return(words.split())


words = gen_wordlist()
```

If I enter a valid filename on the first attempt, it works as it should. However, if I enter an invalid filename and choose to try again, I get the following error, even if my second attempt is definitely a valid filename:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TEST.py", line 20, in <module>
    words = gen_wordlist()
  File "TEST.py", line 15, in gen_wordlist
    words = my_file.read()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_file' referenced before assignment
```

I can't work out why though. Surely, when I select `'y'`, the code just executes from the beginning of the `gen_wordlist()` function, and should work the same as if I had entered a valid filename on the first attempt, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `open()` call raises a `FileNotFoundError` exception, `my_file` was never set and all other references trying to use that name will fail.

That *includes* the code after `gen_wordlist()` was called in the exception handler. Sure, the new call may succeed, but that call then *returns* back to this frame where `my_file` was *not* set.

You want to return here too, instead:

```
if retry == 'y' or retry == 'Y':
    return gen_wordlist()
```

Otherwise you'll ignore the result of the successful recursive call here too.

It's not a great idea to use recursion to handle errors in user input. Use a loop instead:

```
my_file = None

while my_file is None:
    filename = input("Please enter the name of the wordlist:  ")

    try:
        my_file = open(filename, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        retry = input("No file named " + filename + ". Would you like to try again (y/n)")
        if retry.lower() == 'y':
            # back to the top of the loop
            continue

        print("Goodbye :-)")
        sys.exit()
```

This `while` loop then runs until `my_file` has successfully been set to a file object.

Answer (score 0):

Re-read the error message, it clearly says you have used the variable `my_file` before assignment. Now, look at your code, when do you define `my_file` in the `except` clause? The `try` falls out without declaring/assigning to the `my_file` variable in case of an error. Rest, Martijn's answer points out some more issues.